# How to write query in Hibernate with row_number function present in it?

Tags: sql, hql

I want to convert following query to HQL

```
select X.* from (select tbl.*,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Col1 order by Col1) as RANK from table1 tbl where tbl.col2='22'
                    and (
                        tbl.col3 in (
                            'ABC'
                        )
                    ) 
              ) X
             WHERE X.rank = 1;
```

Help required.
This is in context of converting MySQL group by to equivalent group by on Oracle.

EDIT: 
My original MySQL query is

```
select * from table1 tbl 
where tbl.col2='22'
and tbl.col3 in ('ABC','XYZ')
group by col1;
```

I want to convert it first to Oracle equivalent query and then to HQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is very close to this query:

```
select X.*
from table1 tbl
where tbl.col2 = '22' and tbl.col3 = 'ABC' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table tbl2
                  where tbl2.col2 = tbl.col2 and tbl2.col3 = tbl.col3 and
                        tbl2.col1 < tbl.col1
                 );
```

The only difference is how the two queries handle ties on `col1`.  This will return all such values.  Yours will return only one of them.

Perhaps this will work for you in HQL.

Comment: What if Col1 is not a number data type?

Comment: The above should work in both Oracle and MySQL and quite likely in HQL as well.  The `<` operator works for most SQL data types.

Comment: My purpose is to simulate group by, your query might return duplicates if there are duplicate values for col1

Comment: @user3705949 . . . You can fix that if you have a unique id in the table.  Your original query is relying on a MySQL-only extension to `group by`, so it is going to be difficult to port anyway.